# Can I know which endpoint is finally targeted when using load balancer?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route using a customized load balancer as,

```
from("timer://myTimer?period=2000")
.loadBalance(new MyCustomLoadBalancer())
.to("mock:em1").to("mock:em2").to("mock:em3")
.end();
```

In the customized balancer class, it seems only processors can be gotten.

```
public class MyCustomLoadBalancer extends SimpleLoadBalancerSupport {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        List<Processor> pList = getProcessors();
        .......

        //It is wanted to log which endpoint is finally targeted.
        foo.process(exchange);            
    }
}
```

But here, I want to log actually which endpoint is targeted when using this load balancer.
In product environment, Jetty or HTTP endpoints will be used instead of these mock endpoints.
Is there a way to realized this?

===================================================================
Based on the suggestion from Ibsen, I used the Jetty endpoint to do test.

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8043?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.loadBalance(new MyCustomLoadBalancer())
.to("jetty:http://localhost:80?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
.to("jetty:http://www.google.com?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
.end();
```

But the Processors are not class of SendProcessor("foo instanceof SendProcessor" returns false), so I can't get the endpoint by getDestination.
I believe there should be some relationship between the endpoint and processor.

Could you give me more help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Processor is a SendProcessor where you can get the endpoint it will send the exchange to.

```
if (foo instanceof SendProcessor) {
  SendProcessor send = (SendProcessor) foo;
  Endpoint dest = send.getDestination();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
I'd like to do some test on real Jetty endpoint.

Comment: Hi Ibsen,
Is this possible to get all contained endpoint instances in a load balancer? I think a load balancer instace acts as a container.
Also, is it possible to get the corresponding processor instance used by a endpoint instance?
If these work, the problem can also be solved.

Comment: The processor associated with Jetty endpoint is not instance of SendProcessor; I failed to get the endpoint by your suggested method.

I want the load balancer to log the status of each endpoint. So the user can easily know which service is in problem.